# change indentation in VS code for python functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS code to write python code.

When writing functions I get:
[image]

What I would like to have when I hit return after every variable of the method is:
[image]

But after hitting return after the first argument the next line starts just under "def".

After looking for solutions in internet I read somewhere that adding this to settings.json would solve it:

"editor.autoIndent": true,
"editor.indentAfterOpenBracket": "control"
}

But this is not the case and the behavior remains the same.

How and what should be added in settings.json to get this behavior.

Comment: I'm curious whether this is configurable. If you press return just after the opening parenthesis, it will indent 4 spaces. According to PEP 8 however, that should be indented double (8 spaces). Your way of line-breaking/indenting is also valid. PyCharm does it correctly, I see.

Comment: Have you tried the *Python Indent* extension by Kevin Rose?

Comment: @Fractalism I am trying to use barebone VS code. We have a Jupyterhub and my experience is that extensions end up causing problems.

Comment: The problem may not be on vscode's side, but on your formatter's side (who will be called afterwards by vscode). [yapf](https://pypi.org/project/yapf/) may help you ([configuration of vscode for yapf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60055463/18419414)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use balck, you can run command `pip install black` and add the following codes to your settings.json:

```
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
```

You can read [black document](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#how-black-wraps-lines) for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change the indentation of Python functions in VS Code, you can use **YAPF**, you can install the "YAPF Formatter" extension and then configure it to format your code using the desired indentation style. Here are the steps to do this:

- Install the "**YAPF Formatter**" extension in VS Code by searching for it in the Extensions marketplace or by visiting the following link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mr-konn.yapf
- Open the settings.json file in VS Code by going to File > Preferences > Settings or by pressing `Ctrl + ,`
- In the `settings.json` file, add the following lines to configure **YAPF** to use the desired indentation style:

```
    "python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
        "--style={based_on_style: pep8, indent_width: 4}"
    ],
```

- Save the settings.json file and then you can format your python file by going to Edit > Format Document or by using the shortcut key `Ctrl+Shift+I`

Note: You can also configure YAPF to use different indentation style other than the one mentioned in the above example by modifying the indent_width and based_on_style fields in the yapfArgs settings

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such setting in VSCode. To do that you need to use a formatter. You can configure your VSCode to use [Black](https://github.com/psf/black).

It doesn't matter how long the length of the line is, if you put a `,` at the end of your parameters, it puts them in separate lines:

```py
# in
def short(a, b,):
    pass

# out
def short(
    a,
    b,
):
    pass
```

But the parenthesis are problem here(unless you don't care). Black doesn't put them along parameters like how you showed.